PL/SQL finding values from a table within a string
I have a table with a column with the following values:
COWS
SHEEP
GOATS
CHICKENS
I have another table with string rows that look like



ID
STRING




1
PINK


2
SAUSAGES







I want to search within the string to find any instances of the values from my first table.
I've been searching and can figure it out when the values are in the same location each time, or when I can specify exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to search within the string using the values from the other table
using PL/SQL I want to find:
1 COWS
2 SHEEP

select ID, STRING from TABLE2 where STRING in (select COL from TABLE1)

To search for values within a table (lets call it STRINGS)
by referring another table (lets say ANIMALS),
using PL/SQL you need to use loops:-
DECLARE
    v_string_value strings.string%TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR rec_string IN (SELECT ID, STRING FROM strings) LOOP
        v_string_value := rec_string.STRING;
        IF v_string_value IN (SELECT animal_name FROM animals) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_string.ID || ' ' || v_animal_name);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
/


|    I want to search within the string to find any instances of the values 
|    from my first table.

It looks like you want to check if your table values are contained within some strings in another table. Or you want to see if your table values have an exact match in some strings from another table.
Here is a simple example on how you could find either one. Exact match is no. 1 and searched in STRING_1. Contained is no. 2 and searched in STRING_2.
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    search_for_tbl AS
        ( Select 'COWS' "SEARCH_FOR" From Dual Union All 
          Select 'SHEEP' "SEARCH_FOR" From Dual Union All 
          Select 'GOATS' "SEARCH_FOR" From Dual Union All 
          Select 'CHICKEN' "SEARCH_FOR" From Dual 
        ),
    strings_tbl AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 'PINK' "STRING_1", 'PINK IS A COLOR' "STRING_2" From Dual Union All 
          Select 2 "ID", 'SAUSAGES' "STRING_1", 'THEESE SAUSAGES ARE VERY TASTY' "STRING_2" From Dual Union All 
          Select 3 "ID", 'COWS' "STRING_1", 'THERE ARE NO PINK COWS' "STRING_2" From Dual 
        )

You can use Left Join ON condition to find a match or value contained in string:
1. If you are looking for an exact match of SEARCH_FOR and STRING_1 then:
Select  sf.SEARCH_FOR, 
        Case When t.ID Is Null 
             Then 'NOT_FOUND' 
        Else 'FOUND: ( *ID = ' || To_Char(t.ID) || '  /  *STRING_1 = ' || t.STRING_1 || ' )' 
        End "SEARCH_RESULT"
From       search_for_tbl sf
Left Join  strings_tbl t ON(t.STRING_1 = sf.SEARCH_FOR) 

/*    -- R e s u l t : 
SEARCH_ SEARCH_RESULT                                                                     
------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
COWS    FOUND: ( *ID = 3  /  *STRING_1 = COWS )                                           
CHICKEN NOT_FOUND                                                                         
GOATS   NOT_FOUND                                                                         
SHEEP   NOT_FOUND                                                                          */
-- If you want just matching row(s) use Inner instead of Left Join

2. If you are looking for value of SEARCH_FOR contained in STRING_2 column
Select  sf.SEARCH_FOR, 
        Case When t.ID Is Null 
             Then 'NOT_FOUND' 
        Else 'FOUND: ( **ID = ' || To_Char(t.ID) || '  /  **STRING_2 = ' || t.STRING_2 || ' )' 
        End "SEARCH_RESULT"
From       search_for_tbl sf
Left Join  strings_tbl t  ON( t.STRING_2 Like '%' || sf.SEARCH_FOR || '%' )
                 -- OR --> ON( InStr(t.STRING_2, sf.SEARCH_FOR) > 0 )

/*    R e s u l t :
SEARCH_ SEARCH_RESULT                                                                                             
------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
COWS    FOUND: ( **ID = 3  /  **STRING_2 = THERE ARE NO PINK COWS )                             
SHEEP   NOT_FOUND                                                                               
GOATS   NOT_FOUND                                                                               
CHICKEN NOT_FOUND                                                    */
-- If you want just FOUND row(s) filter result with below Where clause

WHERE t.ID Is Not Null

